# How do i change color when i click specific div has own id?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make change color function with useState.
this is my code :

```js
  const [showChart, setShowChart] = useState({ color: "5px solid #c5d5ee" });
  const handleOnClick = e => {
    switch (e.currentTarget.id) {
      case "one":
        setShowChart(1, { color: "5px solid #f17544" });
        break;
      case "two":
        setShowChart(2, { color: "5px solid #f17544" });
        break;
      case "three":
        setShowChart(3, { color: "5px solid #f17544" });
        break;
```

What I want to do is when I click specific div, then the color should change and when i click the other div , then The color that i clicked before should be disappeared , so i tried above code to do that. but the color is not changed. so i don't know what i'm wrong with this

and I'm using `setShowChart(1)` for this :

```js
{showChart === 1 && <ChartMenu setType={setType} />}
      {showChart === 2 && <ChartMenu setType={setType2} />}
      {showChart === 3 && <ChartMenu setType={setType3} />}
      {showChart === 4 && <ChartMenu setType={setType4} />}
      {showChart === 5 && <ChartMenu setType={setType5} />}
      {showChart === 6 && <ChartMenu setType={setType6} />}
      {showChart === 7 && <ChartMenu setType={setType7} />}
      {showChart === 8 && <ChartMenu setType={setType8} />}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this CSS syntax is wrong `color: "5px solid #f17544"`. The correct way: `color: "#f17544"`

If you're attempting to set the border css, using `border: "5px solid #f17544"` instead.

Secondly, why do you set a new state in this way? `setShowChart(1, { color: "5px solid #f17544" });`
What does the number **1** mean?

My suggestion: `setShowChart({ border: "5px solid #f17544" });`

Comment: thanks ! and I edited why i use `setShowChart(1)`

Comment: I need to show up specific menu with `setShowChart` . so I'm trying to use  `setShowChart` to change color as well

Comment: There is a conflict in your code.
The initial state value is an object useState({ color: "5px solid #c5d5ee" }), but you're trying to set state as a number setShowChart(1)

Comment: Can i not to change with that id??

Comment: Should i make new useState for changing color??

Comment: Yes, of course. You can use multiple states in your component.

Comment: Btw, you really need to check the official documentation from React team: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
This will give you an overview of using the useState hook